# Basic Probability Question

Tags: probability

Given 3 phillips head screws, and assuming there are 5 different orientations that are possible when the screw is finally placed into the wood, what is the probability of all 3 screws having the exact same orientation/alignment ? In other words the slots of the screws are all lined up the same.

Comment: The probability can have any value from $0$ to $1$. The value $1/25$ given in the answers are based on the $5$ orientations being _equally likely_ for all the screws and the choice of orientation of each of the screws being _independent_ of the other choices. Neither assumption might hold in an actual situation. In fine carpentry, the three screws might be placed in the _same_ orientation, or two in one orientation and the third in an orthogonal orientation.

Answer (score 2):

1/25.  There are 125 total combinations possible (5)(5)(5) = 125.  5 of those 125 combinations will be the three screws all lined up in the same manner.  5(lined up correctly)/125(total combinations) = 1/25.

Comment: I think that would be all lined up in a pre-specified manner. The first screw doesn't matter, it's whether the next two match the first.

Comment: Right.  That's why the answer is 1/25, and not 1/125.  There is only a 1/125 that the three screws will match, but there are 5 ways in which the screws can match.  So either you don't consider the first screw and it's (1/5)(1/5) for the next two, or you consider the first screw and say that there is a 1/125 chance that the screws will match, and 5 different ways for the screws to match = 5/125 = 1/25.

Comment: Yeah, but the point is, although there are 25 attempts to get to the expected match on average, you need 27 screws to even test this.

Answer (score 2):

There are $n_s = 3$ screws and $n_o = 5$ orientations. The probability for each orientation is $p_o = 1/n_o = 1/5$.

If the first screw is aligned, it can have any orientation. But the two other screws have to match the orientation of the first. Hence, the probability that the screws are all lined up is $$p_o^{n_s - 1} = \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2 = 1/25 = 0.04\text{.}$$

Comment: Ah...thanks for that. I initially was thinking (1/5) to the third power. So, on the average, it would take at least 25 + 2 screws to get one 3 screw matched sequence. Is that statement correct ?

Comment: No. You might be able to place $10$ screws and have no triple match, but it is guaranteed that the $11$-th screw will give you three that are in the same orientation

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention: it must be 3 IN A ROW...not just ANY 3 screws.

Comment: This problem is now degenerating into sheer nonsense.